# atomic - Deleted Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, vector, stdatomic

A class, having an *array* of atomic objects as one of it's private data member, is desired.

```
class A {
  vector<atomic<int>> arr;
  public:
    A(int size, int init) : arr(vector<atomic<int>>(size,init)) {} 
      // Error: Deleted 'atomic(const atomic&)' (GCC)
};
```

Fairly simple, the copy constructor is deleted. All I want to do is initialize each of the entries in `arr` to `init`. I am able to do this using pointer and dynamic allocation.

```
class A {
  atomic<int> *arr;
  public:
    A(int size, int init) : arr(new atomic<int>[size]) {
      for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) arr[i]=init; // Not initialization, but works
    } 
};
```

But I want to do this using vectors (`C++`ish way). I tried explicitly assigning to vector elements, but even `vector::resize()` and `vector::push_back()` requires a copy ctor.

```
class A {
  vector<atomic<int>> arr;
  public:
    A(int size, int init) { 
      arr.resize(size); // Error: Deleted 'atomic(const atomic&)' (GCC)
      for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) arr[i]=init;
    }
};
```

Is there any hack possible or pointer one is the only alternative?

Thank You.

Comment: Why not `arr(size, init)`?

Comment: [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) constructs items in place. Unfortunately, because of the potential needed reallocation it also requires T be MoveInsertable, which atomics don't satisfy.

Answer (score 4):

You may do

```
A(int size, int init) : arr(size)
{
    for (auto& e : arr) {
        e = init;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7a6c2d469d72ad7)

Comment: Yes, it works. But again, it's not initialization which is originally desired. Can this explicit assignment be avoided?